# Getting one value from SQL select statement in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, sql

I'm trying to return a value from a select statement. Its only one value because the value I'm returning is from the primary key column.

The SQL statement is `SELECT itemNo FROM item WHERE itemName = 'astringvalue';`

My method for getting the value looks like this:

```
private String viewValue(Connection con, String command) throws SQLException 
    {
        String value = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try 
        {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(command);

            while (rs.next())
                value = rs.toString();
        } 

        catch (SQLException e ) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        finally
        {
            if (stmt != 
            null) { stmt.close(); }
        }

        return value;

    }
```

I do have a `getConnection()` method too.

Here is what im using to call the `viewValue`method:

```
if((action.getSource() == btnSave) ||(action.getSource() == btnSavePrint) )
        {
            String findItemNoCommand = "SELECT itemNo FROM `item` WHERE itemName = '" + itemList.getSelectedItem() + "'";

            try 
            {
                itemNo = viewValue(conn, findItemNoCommand);
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(itemNo);
        }
```

The code above was written for a `ButtonHandler`

Right now, for the `println` I'm getting a "`com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@1e72cae`" .. I don't understand how it is so.. but I'm assuming that ResultSet is the wrong choice here.

My question is.. what can i use there that can work?

Any help or clue as to what im doing wrong is much appreciated.

Comment: You need `value = rs.getString(1);`

Comment: And change `while(rs.next())` to `if(rs.next())` since you only need one value.

Comment: You should use try with resources when possible (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
This would eliminate the finally block from your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Right now, for the `println` I'm getting a "`com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@1e72cae`"

is because you return the `ResultSet` object here , `value = rs.toString();`

From [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html),

> A ResultSet object is a table of data representing a database result
> set, which is usually generated by executing a statement that queries
> the database
>
> You access the data in a ResultSet object through a cursor. Note that
> this cursor is not a database cursor. This cursor is a pointer that
> points to one row of data in the ResultSet. Initially, the cursor is
> positioned before the first row. The method ResultSet.next moves the
> cursor to the next row. This method returns false if the cursor is
> positioned after the last row. This method repeatedly calls the
> ResultSet.next method with a while loop to iterate through all the
> data in the ResultSet.

You should tell the result set to get the value from the column ,

```
value = rs.getString(1);
```

through index

```
value = rs.getString("itemNo");
```

or through column name

Answer (score 4):

Change :

```
value = rs.toString();
```

To:

```
value = rs.getString(1);
```

rs.toString returns the result of the `toString` method of the Object `ResultSet`.
`rs.getString(1)` gives you the first parameter of the resultset as a `String`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `rs.getInt(1)` or `rs.getString(1)` to retrieve the actual value from the `ResultSet`. Then read a JDBC tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

change it to

```
if(rs.next())
```

and

```
rs.getString("itemNo");
```

works !!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
while (rs.next())
    value = rs.toString();
```

to

```
 while (rs.next())
    value = rs.getString("itemNo");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
private String viewValue(Connection con, String command) throws SQLException 
{
    String value = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try 
    {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(command);

        while (rs.next())
            value = rs.getString(1);
    } 

    catch (SQLException e ) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    finally
    {
        if (stmt != 
        null) { stmt.close(); }
    }

    return value;

}
```